# Change options of select in jquery-image-dropdown plugin

Tags: jquery

I would like to dynamically clear the previously set list of options in the select, and add one new value to the list. The select is built with the use of the below plugin:

[Plugin jquery-image-dropdown webpage](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/blog/jquery-image-dropdown)

My jquery code does not work:

```
    $('#selector-1').empty();
    $('#selector-1').append($('<option>', {
        value: 1,
        text: 'One'
    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown/blob/master/examples/help.html):

> `destroy` Restore the original dorpdown [sic]

```
var oDropdown = $("#element").msDropdown().data("dd");
oDropdown.destroy()
```

---

In your case, the following should work:

```
var selectEl = $('#selector-1');
var dropDownInstance = selectEl.msDropDown().data('dd');

// Destroy/add new options.
dropDownInstance.destroy();

selectEl
    .empty()
    .append($('<option>', {
        value: 1,
        text: 'One'
    }))
    .msDropDown().data('dd');
```